# Media query not working for iphone width 320px

Tags: css, media-queries

I want this image in the html tag to only fill the max-width of 320px like it's supposed to. However it's going beyond that. Horizontal scroll bars show up and image tiles for 166 more pixels. In the IOS simulator and my ipone All the other elements span the width correctly.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
html {
margin:0; 
padding:0;
background: url('../_images/iphoneCardboard_flat.png')repeat;
}
```

Update: These are some tags that might be relevant.

```
#band1 {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
height:50px;
width:100%;
background-image: url('../_images/iphoneGradient.png');
z-index:-1;
}

.barbLogo {
position: absolute;
top:3px;
margin-left:165px; 
width:320px;
}

#band2{
position: absolute;
top:-75px;
left:0;
height:50px;
width:100%;
background-image: url('../_images/iphoneGradient.png');
z-index:-1;
}

#gridBgContainer{
position: absolute;
margin:0;
top:50px;
left:0;
height:200px;
background:url('../_images/gridBg.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
display: table;
z-index: 1;
}

#wrapper {
position: relative;
top:0px;
left:0;
right:0;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
width:100%;
text-align: center;
z-index: 3;
}

#socialLinks {
position: absolute;
margin-top: 14px; 
float:right;
right:0px;
}

#top-menu {
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left: 0px;
width:320px;
z-index: 100; 
}

section#homeContent {
position: absolute;
top: 400px;
width:320px;
z-index: 10;
}

section#faqContent {
position: absolute;
top:900px;
width:320px;
z-index: 10;
text-align:left;
}

footer {
position: absolute;
font-size: 1.15em;
top: 1230px;
padding: 0 1% 0 1%;
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 10;
}

.footer{
text-align:center;
padding: 2% 0 0 0;
}

#band3{
position: absolute;
top: 1255px;
left:0;
height:50px;
width:100%;
background-image: url('../_images/iphoneGradient.png')repeat-x;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: it's a background image, so it can't be causing the scrollbars issue. Please post the full relevant code...

Comment: Thanks for responding, I added some code hopefully it's something simple!

Answer (score 0):

you should set the width property

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
html {
margin:0; 
padding:0;
background: url('../_images/iphoneCardboard_flat.png')repeat;

width: 320px;

}
```